# PHP jQuery Tag-It - showing label from value list

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I try an awesome plugin (http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/). I successfully pass the related product and store it into a list of ids to mysql.

For the related product, i have the list

```
var RelatedProducts = [{value:142,label:'Canon'},{value:150,label:'Nikon'},{value:174,label:'Sony'}]
```

I stored the value list into mysql:

```
related: 142,150,174
```

How can I display the related product by showing the label, insteads of showing the related ids?

Current display:

```
 Related Product: 142,150,174
```

I want to show my display list like this with some extra label:

```
Related Product: Canon,Nikon,Sony
```

Could anyone please help me here? I would be very much appreciated!

Comment: So your mysql column value is `142,150,174`, a csv? Do you have another table that has the product names `Canon,Nikon,Sony` with their associated `id`s?

Comment: `142,150,174` use this to identify the items from `RelatedProducts` and then construct the display.the other option is store the text in some other column and select it in mysql to show.

Comment: 142,150,174 is id of category that the product related to.

I have a mysql table: tbl_category
id, name
142, Canon
150, Nikon
174, Sony
180, Leica

Comment: if possible show the table view in image.

Comment: store the labels along with id in table and do the job. Make life easy :)